# Removing duplicate GeoJSON linestrings whilst favouring an object with more properties.in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, gis, geojson

I am struggling with a filtering function to remove certain duplicates from an GeoJSON array.

Considering the following function:

```
export const removeDuplicateGeoms = arr => {
  return arr.filter(
    (v, i, a) =>
      a.findIndex(t => {
        const parser = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
        return parser.read(t.geometry).equals(parser.read(v.geometry));
      }) === i,
  );
};
```

This effectively removes duplicate geometries from an array of GeoJSON objects. In this case, highway data. However, in the case of duplicates, I need it to return the one which has certain properties, in this case 'maintenanceresponsibility', complete.

Example data:

```
[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "vw_os_highways_street_live1.fid-3966bc9c_17367a40938_-4ba9",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [470614.907, 181433.133, 89.1],
            [470612.073, 181429.014, 89.7],
            [470610, 181426, 90.2],
            [470598.697, 181406.249, 93],
            [470590.271, 181395.977, 94.3],
            [470579.758, 181388.916, 95.7],
            [470571.092, 181383.94, 96.7],
            [470550, 181375, 99.1],
            [470525, 181366, 100.8],
            [470495, 181355, 102.1],
            [470483.107, 181350.921, 102.3]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
        "roadlink_id": "osgb4000000023302942",
        "roadclassification": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "formofway": "Single Carriageway",
        "roadclassificationnumber": null,
        "operationalstate": "Open",
        "roadname": "",
        "usrn": "usrn83000638",
        "validfrom": "2017-01-04T00:00:00Z",
        "streettype": "Numbered Street",
        "roadclassification_street": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "designatedname1": "",
        "nationalroadcode": "",
        "maintenanceresponsibility": null,
        "highwayauthorityname": null,
        "locationdescription": null,
        "designation": null,
        "designation_description": null
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "vw_os_highways_street_live1.fid-3966bc9c_17367a40938_-4ba6",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [470614.907, 181433.133, 89.1],
            [470612.073, 181429.014, 89.7],
            [470610, 181426, 90.2],
            [470598.697, 181406.249, 93],
            [470590.271, 181395.977, 94.3],
            [470579.758, 181388.916, 95.7],
            [470571.092, 181383.94, 96.7],
            [470550, 181375, 99.1],
            [470525, 181366, 100.8],
            [470495, 181355, 102.1],
            [470483.107, 181350.921, 102.3]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
        "roadlink_id": "osgb4000000023302942",
        "roadclassification": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "formofway": "Single Carriageway",
        "roadclassificationnumber": null,
        "operationalstate": "Open",
        "roadname": "",
        "usrn": "usrn36216412",
        "validfrom": "2014-01-10T00:00:00Z",
        "streettype": "Officially Described Street",
        "roadclassification_street": "",
        "designatedname1": "",
        "nationalroadcode": "",
        "maintenanceresponsibility": "Maintainable At Public Expense",
        "highwayauthorityname": "Oxfordshire",
        "locationdescription": "",
        "designation": null,
        "designation_description": null
    }
}]
```

Wild success for this sample would return the 2nd object returned in the filter.

Anyone have any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way to do this would be iterating through the results, then iterating through the keys of the array's properties array, checking if the value of that property key is `null`, then add one point to a "null property" variable and finally sorting the list by the smallest count of null properties.

```js
const list = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "vw_os_highways_street_live1.fid-3966bc9c_17367a40938_-4ba9",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [470614.907, 181433.133, 89.1],
            [470612.073, 181429.014, 89.7],
            [470610, 181426, 90.2],
            [470598.697, 181406.249, 93],
            [470590.271, 181395.977, 94.3],
            [470579.758, 181388.916, 95.7],
            [470571.092, 181383.94, 96.7],
            [470550, 181375, 99.1],
            [470525, 181366, 100.8],
            [470495, 181355, 102.1],
            [470483.107, 181350.921, 102.3]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
        "roadlink_id": "osgb4000000023302942",
        "roadclassification": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "formofway": "Single Carriageway",
        "roadclassificationnumber": null,
        "operationalstate": "Open",
        "roadname": "",
        "usrn": "usrn83000638",
        "validfrom": "2017-01-04T00:00:00Z",
        "streettype": "Numbered Street",
        "roadclassification_street": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "designatedname1": "",
        "nationalroadcode": "",
        "maintenanceresponsibility": null,
        "highwayauthorityname": null,
        "locationdescription": null,
        "designation": null,
        "designation_description": null
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "vw_os_highways_street_live1.fid-3966bc9c_17367a40938_-4ba6",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [470614.907, 181433.133, 89.1],
            [470612.073, 181429.014, 89.7],
            [470610, 181426, 90.2],
            [470598.697, 181406.249, 93],
            [470590.271, 181395.977, 94.3],
            [470579.758, 181388.916, 95.7],
            [470571.092, 181383.94, 96.7],
            [470550, 181375, 99.1],
            [470525, 181366, 100.8],
            [470495, 181355, 102.1],
            [470483.107, 181350.921, 102.3]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
        "roadlink_id": "osgb4000000023302942",
        "roadclassification": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "formofway": "Single Carriageway",
        "roadclassificationnumber": null,
        "operationalstate": "Open",
        "roadname": "",
        "usrn": "usrn36216412",
        "validfrom": "2014-01-10T00:00:00Z",
        "streettype": "Officially Described Street",
        "roadclassification_street": "",
        "designatedname1": "",
        "nationalroadcode": "",
        "maintenanceresponsibility": "Maintainable At Public Expense",
        "highwayauthorityname": "Oxfordshire",
        "locationdescription": "",
        "designation": null,
        "designation_description": null
    }
}];

for(let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    list[index].null_properties = 0;
  
    for(let key in list[index].properties)
        if(list[index].properties[key] == null)
            list[index].null_properties++;
}

list.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.null_properties - b.null_properties;
});

console.log("list sorted by the smallest count of null properties:");
console.log(list);
```

The final answer would be `list[0]` in this case as it has the least amount of null references. Worth pointing out to check if the list length is 0 before assuming there is several objects.

**EDIT**:

Since OP needs the list to keep its order, you can create another array which stores the index and the null reference counts, then sort that array by the least null references, and then accessing the original list using that index.

```js
const list = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "vw_os_highways_street_live1.fid-3966bc9c_17367a40938_-4ba9",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [470614.907, 181433.133, 89.1],
            [470612.073, 181429.014, 89.7],
            [470610, 181426, 90.2],
            [470598.697, 181406.249, 93],
            [470590.271, 181395.977, 94.3],
            [470579.758, 181388.916, 95.7],
            [470571.092, 181383.94, 96.7],
            [470550, 181375, 99.1],
            [470525, 181366, 100.8],
            [470495, 181355, 102.1],
            [470483.107, 181350.921, 102.3]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
        "roadlink_id": "osgb4000000023302942",
        "roadclassification": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "formofway": "Single Carriageway",
        "roadclassificationnumber": null,
        "operationalstate": "Open",
        "roadname": "",
        "usrn": "usrn83000638",
        "validfrom": "2017-01-04T00:00:00Z",
        "streettype": "Numbered Street",
        "roadclassification_street": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "designatedname1": "",
        "nationalroadcode": "",
        "maintenanceresponsibility": null,
        "highwayauthorityname": null,
        "locationdescription": null,
        "designation": null,
        "designation_description": null
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "vw_os_highways_street_live1.fid-3966bc9c_17367a40938_-4ba6",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [470614.907, 181433.133, 89.1],
            [470612.073, 181429.014, 89.7],
            [470610, 181426, 90.2],
            [470598.697, 181406.249, 93],
            [470590.271, 181395.977, 94.3],
            [470579.758, 181388.916, 95.7],
            [470571.092, 181383.94, 96.7],
            [470550, 181375, 99.1],
            [470525, 181366, 100.8],
            [470495, 181355, 102.1],
            [470483.107, 181350.921, 102.3]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "geom",
    "properties": {
        "roadlink_id": "osgb4000000023302942",
        "roadclassification": "Classified Unnumbered",
        "formofway": "Single Carriageway",
        "roadclassificationnumber": null,
        "operationalstate": "Open",
        "roadname": "",
        "usrn": "usrn36216412",
        "validfrom": "2014-01-10T00:00:00Z",
        "streettype": "Officially Described Street",
        "roadclassification_street": "",
        "designatedname1": "",
        "nationalroadcode": "",
        "maintenanceresponsibility": "Maintainable At Public Expense",
        "highwayauthorityname": "Oxfordshire",
        "locationdescription": "",
        "designation": null,
        "designation_description": null
    }
}];

const null_references = [];

for(let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        let count = 0;
  
    for(let key in list[index].properties)
        if(list[index].properties[key] == null)
            count++;
            
        null_references.push({ index, count });
}

null_references.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.count - b.count;
});

console.log("index with the least null references:");
console.log(null_references[0].index);

console.log("all results:");
console.log(null_references);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the data is already sorted by distance from a centroid and I need to keep the sort order.

Comment: You can then iterate through the array to find out the index of the object with the least null references.

I've edited my code to provide an example.